# Python app on AWS requirements.txt not installing private git repo

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip

I am hosting a python app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The `requirements.txt` file contains a private repo in the form of `git+ssh://git@github.com/REPONAME.git`. I generated a private key on the server, added the public key to the repo's deploy key and tested that that AWS server has access to the repo (`ssh -T git@github.com`).

When deploying the app, I keep getting the error:

> Cloning ssh://git@github.com/REPONAME.git to /tmp/pip-gxaX0d-build
> Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I have not been able to solve this issue.

Comment: How did you `deploy`? Can you show us the commands?

Comment: I use the aws cli, so from my local machine i just type eb deploy